# How to install Linux capabilities like setcap and getcap?

Tags: linux, opensuse, capabilities

In my openSUSE 13.2 machine I can apply commands like `setcap` and `getcap` on some application. I moved that application to an openSUSE 12 machine that does not have capabilities installed. In the 13.2 machine I have packages `libcap-ng0`, `libcap1`, `libcap1-32bit`, `libcap2` and `libcap2-32bit` installed, I installed the same packages on the openSUSE 12 machine and I still get this message:

```
If 'setcap' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it
```

Even on root. I just don't remember how I got capabilities to work on my machine. How to install these commands so I can set file capabilities ?

Comment: You need libcap-progs

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked. Mind to post it as an answer ?

Comment: It is ok, I am glad it worked. :)

Comment: I mean you post not me :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need libcap-progs

```
sudo zypper install libcap-progs
```

Comment: Is this answer only for Suse? Because I'm not able to find `libcap-progs` on `.deb` systems. Where it is more likely the package `libcap2-bin`

Comment: @Sandburg you'll want to use the Debian tool to search for a likely equivalent, but also good idea to the google that likely suspect to make sure it's correct/authentic.  `dpkg  -l '''libcap'''` https://wiki.debian.org/PackageManagement/Searching https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg.1.html